Multiple HTF EMA
Why daily EMA20 is a stepping line not a smooth one. like weekly or monthly EMA
string custTime = na
if timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.isminutes
    custTime:=input.timeframe("D","Daily")
else if timeframe.isweekly
    custTime := input.timeframe("W","Weekly")
else if timeframe.ismonthly
    custTime := input.timeframe("M","Monthly")
ema = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, custTime, ta.ema(close, 20))
plot(ema, "Plot_EMA",color=color.blue, linewidth=2)

i am expecting daily ema20 line in daily or lower time frame, weekly ema in weekly time frame

For a smooth line (not stepped) use barmerge.gaps_on
ema = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, custTime, ta.ema(close, 20), gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)


Thanks. now everything is working fine as I was expecting
